# Can i customize the backend to the following features?

Tags: admin, module, backend, custom-options

I am a newbie. I am planning on opening a greeting card shop in which the users can customize it. So they will get fields depending on the type of card they choose. Some of them, they just need to fill in text, and for the others, they need to upload image as well. For some products there will be follow-up products as well.

I want the backend to be able to allow me to enter as many fields as I want, and and the field type. Are these possible with Magento? Is Magento the good solution for this?

Comment: For Magento Go, but relevant: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/custom-variants-options/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @benmarks pointed out Product custom options is the way to go.

These will allow you to choose from a large range of input types such as textfields, radio buttons, files etc which the customer can use to configure a product. Also you can add prices to these options.

Go to the backend `Catalog > Product > [choose your product] > Custom options tab` and there you can configure the fields per product.

[image]

Comment: Is this functionality available to the Community Edition as well?

Comment: Yes it is. Check my update